# Cloud Vision: What gets billed, the call or the successful completion of the call?

Tags: google-vision

We are just thinking whether to validate some input for google vision (OCR).
We can either throw everything at google vision and check the result, or we validate client side and hope to minimize BadRequest responses.

For us it depends on whether google vision would charge for a BadRequest, like image too large or of the wrong type.

I can't find it the documentation. Does anyone know?